# Trying to insert date and time in sql server but getting error

Tags: c#, sql-server

What is wrong in the following code? im storing the date n time into datetime field in sql server.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string d = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into trans values("+label9.Text+",'d');";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        int x= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Attendance recorded succesfully");
```

Comment: can you try storing the date in a variable first and then insert it in the database

Comment: also your commandText statement could be the issue

Comment: What is the text in this label?  And you should take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Comment: well first of all you should state the error, are you inserting string into a date field ? And your string values should be in single quotes `'`

Comment: text in d label is a integer value.. @Paddy

Comment: some body please give me the correct modified code...

Comment: would you be able to debug the code and let us know what is value in command text?

Answer (score 4):

It is a very bad approach, because it opened for sql-injections. You better use SqlParameter.

```
cmd.CommandText="insert into trans values(@label, @date)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("label", int.Parse(label9.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", DateTime.Now);
cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();
int x= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is mistyping in `CommandText` string. Use this instead

```
cmd.CommandText="insert into trans values("+label9.Text+","+DateTime.Now.ToString()+");";
```

**EDIT:**

Full edited code will be like this. Note that `using` statements will care for disposing your updates, but this code is still bad and a house of **sql-injections**. You must use parameters instead if you want safe code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; Initial Datalog=myDatabase; Integrated Security=TRUE;")) 
  {
      using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("insert into trans values("+label9.Text+","+DateTime.Now.ToString()+");", connection)) 
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is still vulnerable to **SQL injection** - not a good idea! And: since you concatenate together the SQL statement, you need to know what date format the target SQL Server is using - again: not a good idea. Would be **much better** to use a SQL parameter of type `DateTime` that would solve both problems with ease

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that you are using inline SQL, which is just bad.  You should be using `@param1` syntax in the query and then adding parameters to it instead (thus sidestepping this issue also).  Even better - use an ORM like Linq to Sql or Entity Framework (or nHibernate or whatever).

SQL Server generally wants it's times in yyyymmdd format, and also you really should be checking the label's value is indeed an integer and only running the query if it is:

```
int labelValue = 0;
if(int.TryParse(label9.Text, out labelValue))
{
  cmd.CommandText="insert into trans values("+ labelValue +
    ", '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");"')"; 
  cmd.Connection = con;      
  con.Open();      
  int x= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();      
  MessageBox.Show("Attendance recorded succesfully");
}
```

I'd also say you really need to examine your usage of the connection/command - where do you `Dispose`?  Judging by this code, I'm guessing you don't?

All in all, even with these fixes I'm not recommending you do things this way - do it the way that Harm suggests - the +5 (or more) there is deserved.

Comment: For language- and dateformat-indepedent date string, use the short ISO-8601 format which is `YYYYMMDD` (**without** any dashes!) Your solution will e.g. **not** work with any of the European languages (British, German, French, Italian) - that date format will **fail** on such a SQL Server instance....

Comment: @marc_s okay cool, thanks have edited.  On every SQL instance I've ever used this format works - but that's because they've always been the same locale no doubt (that's british, by the way).

Comment: Better would be to not use a string to store dates/times in Sql!  Use a datetime column and sql parameters.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, well, of course, ultimately this method of DB access stinks!  And actually I just realised that there need to be quotes around the datetime literal